# Find cell whose value ends with a given number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to find help with the following:

- I have 2 worksheets (SHEET1 and SHEET2)
- In SHEET1 there's Column A and B: in Column A users can fill in a number 1 to 50.
- In worksheet SHEET2 there is a table with a column A with a code, which is basically a number with an R in front of it ( e.g. R1 to R50), and a column B that displays a date.

What I want to do:
I want to be able to fill in '25' in SHEET1 cell A1, and then in cell B1 I would like to display the date that was found in the column right of the cell that says 'R25'.

I tried VLOOKUP codes, but I can not find a way to 'trim' the R of the 'code' in SHEET2.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP("R"&A1,A1:B20,2)
```

where A1 is cell with coresponding number in sheet1
A1:B20 is range in sheet2